# Windows laptop waking on touchpad click

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-10, power-management

I have a laptop that keeps waking from sleep. My cat sits on the laptop when it is closed and the screen bends which clicks the touchpad button. I can't turn off the wake setting on my touchpad in Windows 10. Is there any way to prevent the laptop from waking up?

Answer (score 0):

Launch Device Manager (open the start menu, type "device manager", launch it), find the Touchpad and see if you find something like this:

[image]